# Python: Invalid Literal for Int() Base 10

Tags: python, literals, radix

I'm writing code for a project to determine the validity of credit cards and i've hit a wall, it seems like all of the things i have tried so far are not working.

This is giving me an error for the sumofodds function where j=int(card[i])

The error is "Invalid Literal for Int() with Base 10

Is there anyone that can give me some advce?

```
def sumofdoubles():
    card=input()
    x=len(card)
    summ=0

    for i in range(x-2,-1,-2):
        j=int(card[i])
        u=j+j

        if u>9:
            h=u/2
            summ=summ+h

     return(summ)

def sumofevens():
    card=input()
    x=len(card)
    summ=0

    for i in range(x-2,-1,-2):
        j=int(card[i])
        u=j+j
        if u<9:
            summ=summ+u

    return(summ)


def sumofodds():
    summ=0
    card=input()
    x=len(card)

    for i in range(x-1,-1,-2):
        j=int(card[i])
        summ=summ+j

    return(summ)

def main():
    card=input()
    length=len(card)
    summ=0

    while(card!="#####"):
        if (card[0]=='4' or card[0]=='5' or card[0]=='6' or (card[0]=='3' and      card[1]=='1')):
            dbls=sumofdoubles()
            evens=sumofevens()
            odds=sumofodds()
            if((dbls+evens+odds)%10==0):
                print("Valid")

main()
```

This is the full traceback for those wondering

```
    python test.py<s.input
    File "test.py", line 52 in <module>
      main()
    File "test.py", line 48, in main
      odds=sumofodds()
    File "test.py", line 33, in sumofodds
      j=int(card[i])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#'
```

Comment: What's the full traceback? What do you type into the console?

Comment: Well, on one of the ``j=int(card[i])`` calls the input (i.e., the ith character of the card) is not a valid integer number. My guess is it is a dash or space, either of which would give that error. Without more details, it is hard to tell exactly.

Comment: looks like you typed a `#` which isn't a number...

Comment: I need to use the "#####" for my sentinel value though

Comment: In that case you'll need to add a test (i.e., ``if`` statement) for your sentinel value before the ``int()`` call and take the appropriate action if it is found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, whatever you did you typed in something that isn't actually a Base 10 number. This includes anything that isn't number characters or spaces. So don't type in that. :-)

Examples:

```
>>> int('04.9')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '04.9'

>>> int('4-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4-'

>>> int("Jack")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Jack'
```

Update: Yes you typed a '#'. That's not a valid number.

Comment: @James It's not working as you think it is. Python is an imperative language. It will only check the card value when the test is reached. It will not check the card value at any other time.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `input` each time you go into `sumofodds`, `sumofevens`, or `sumofdoubles`, so each of them will be working on a separate credit card number. You probably only want to be calling `input` in `main` and should be passing `card` as an argument to each of those other functions.

Your functions then might look something like this:

```
def sum_of_odds(card):
    x = len(card)
    # ...

# ...

def main():
    while True:
        card = input()
        if card == '#####':
            break
        odds = sum_of_odds(card)
        # ...
```

Comment: Is it possible to put the input outside of all the functions, because i've tried and i've gotten errors like:
unbound local error: card is referenced before assignment

Comment: @James: Sure you can with a global, but those are somewhat bad practice; I've edited my answer to show some code that would use arguments.