# Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

These are my code files.

views.py

```
import json
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

from updates.api.mixins import CSRFExemptMixin
from updates.forms import UpdateModelForm
from updates.models import Update as UpdateModel

from cfeapi.mixins import HttpResponseMixin

class UpdateModelDetailAPIView(HttpResponseMixin, CSRFExemptMixin, View): ## <--- here is the problem
   '''
   Retreive, Update, Delete
   '''
   is_json = True

   def get_object(self, id=None):
       # try:
       #   obj = UpdateModel.objects.get(id=id)
       # except UpdateModel.DoesNotExist:
       #   obj = None
       '''
       Below handles DoesNotExist Exception too
       '''
       qs = UpdateModel.objects.filter(id=id)
       if qs.count() == 1:
           return qs.first()
       return None


   def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
       obj = self.get_object(id=id)
       # obj = UpdateModel.objects.get(id=id)
       # print(obj)
       if obj is None:
           error_data = json.dumps({'message' : 'Update not found'})
           return self.render_to_response(error_data, status=404)
       json_data = obj.serialize()
       return self.render_to_response(json_data)
```

mixins.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


class CSRFExemptMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, *kwargs)
```

form.py --- the super() leads here in CSRFExemptMixin

```
from django import forms
from .models import Update as UpdateModel

class UpdateModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UpdateModel
        fields = [
                'user',
                'content',
                'image'
        ]


    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        content = data.get('content', None)
        if content == "":
            content = None
        image = data.get('image', None)
        if content is None and image is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Content or image is required.')
        return super().clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that when is run my code like this

```
class UpdateModelDetailAPIView(HttpResponseMixin, View):
```

It runs perfectly without showing me the error.

But when I run it like this below.

```
class UpdateModelDetailAPIView(HttpResponseMixin, CSRFExemptMixin, View):
```

It shows me the error.

```
File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Django2_byExample_practice\apituts\cfeapi\updates\api\mixins.py" in dispatch
  8.        return super().dispatch(*args, *kwargs) #super(CSRFExemptMixin, self)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Django2_byExample_practice\apituts\cfeapi\updates\api\views.py" in get
  36.       obj = self.get_object(id=id)

File "D:\Django2_byExample_practice\apituts\cfeapi\updates\api\views.py" in get_object
  29.       qs = UpdateModel.objects.filter(id=id)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  892.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  910.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1290.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1318.                     split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1251.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_lookup
  1116.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  20.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  70.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "C:\Users\Nitin NiK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  968.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /api/updates/2/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'
```

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you made any attempt whatsoever to narrow down the problem? Read [ask], [mcve], and probably https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Invalid Literal for Int() Base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993238/python-invalid-literal-for-int-base-10)

Comment: your suggested question helped me to understand more things about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled the second character `*` before `kwargs` in the block.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


class CSRFExemptMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, *kwargs)
```

Check `super().dispatch(*args, *kwargs)` call, where you send `*kwargs` instead of `**kwargs`.