# Value Error: Invalid literal invalid literal for int() with base 10:3,5

Tags: python

**This is supposed to be my output**
Enter your choice: 3
Enter the value of the base followed by the exponent: 5 3
The power of 5 raised to 3 is 125.

```
n,exp=int(input("Enter the value of the base followed by the exponent:")).split(",")
  def power(n,exp):
     if(exp==1):
        return(n)
     if(exp!=1):
       return(n*power(n,exp-1))
print("The power of",n, "raised to",exp,"is",power(n,exp))
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXWV9.png)

Comment: Please don't post links to images of code, traceback or other text. Put the text in the question instead. See [why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/389289)

Comment: What exactly have you done to try to solve this? It’s 7 lines of code, and an extremely common error. **It’s a duplicate, too:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/15993238/11301900. I strongly recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. As an aside, why is your code lacking in whitespace on ever single line? Like `if(exp==1):`, for example. No whitespace, and unnecessary parentheses (to be able to purge all whitespace?). Doesn’t `if exp == 1:` look cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert `5, 3` to an int. split it first and convert the results to an int

```
n, exp = [int(x) for x in input("Enter the value of the base followed by the exponent:").split(",")]
```

You should also avoid using the same variables names for global and functions.